# How to add /.vim directory and all of it's subdirectories to a git repository

Tags: git, vim

Here's my `~/.gitignore` file:

```
# ignore everything
*
# don't ignore these files
!*.vimrc
!*.vim
!*.bashrc
!.gitignore
```

The problem is that `.vim` is a directory and I want to include it (and all of its sub folders) in this git repository; however, they aren't included with my current gitignore file.

I've also tried this:

```
# ignore everything
*
# don't ignore these files
!*.vimrc
!*.vim/
!*.bashrc
!.gitignore
```

and this:

```
# ignore everything
*
# don't ignore these files
!*.vimrc
!*.vim/*
!*.bashrc
!.gitignore
```

How can I ensure that the vim directory and its subdirectories are included in this git repository?

Comment: Normally (well... it depends on flags) the name `.vim` is *not* matched by `*.vim` as the leading dot "hides" from the "glob" `*` character.  So `*.vim` means, for instance, `eggs.vim`, `ham.vim`, and `spam.vim`, but *not* `.vim`.  Just remove the `*` in this case.

Comment: should I remove the `*` from .vimrc/.bashrc as well then? I don't need it to match anything.vimrc or anything.bashrc

Comment: Yes.  By the way, it's not something to worry about with git, but all of this name matching stuff comes in several forms: not just the do/don't handle leading dot specially, but whether the patterns are so-called "glob" patterns (git) or "regular expressions" (hg supports these, regex is more general than glob but harder to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `!.vim/` or `!.vim/**`

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore has this tip:

> A trailing `"/**"` matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.

Comment: Hmm, this only works for me if I also change the `*` to `/*`. What version are you running?

Comment: Are you referring to the `*` before `.vim` ?

Comment: If so, notice that I removed that.

Comment: No, referring to OP's `# ignore everything` line, `*`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `-f` flag to add it to git

> #### `-f/--force`
>
> Allow adding otherwise ignored files.

```
git add -f .vim
```

Comment: If I make changes to the vim folder will I need to add them again with the -f flag in order to commit them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your version of git is later than 1.8.4 then the following should work in your gitignore file.

```
#ignore everything
*
#don't ignore these files
!*/
!.vim/**
```

The `*` pattern ignores everything **including the parent directory** and it is not possible to re-include anything if it's parent directory is excluded.

The pattern `!*/` re-includes all directories, allowing you to use the double-wildcard `!.vim/**` to re-include everything under the .vim directory.

This has been tested to work under git version `2.5.0`